# Using UIPanGestureRecognizer to change images in UIImageView Swift 4

Tags: swift, xcode, uipangesturerecognizer

I have loaded 31 images into a `UIImageView` and would like to use the `UIPanGestureRecognizer` to have the user simply pan up and down to change the images. The only example I could find is in `Obj-C` and can seem to figure out how to make it work. So far I have try to used the following code:

```
 @IBAction func panPerformed(_ sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    if sender.state == .began || sender.state == .changed {
        let translation = sender.translation(in: self.view).y
        //print (translation)
        if translation > 0 {  //swipe up

        } else {  //swipe down
            var pos = Int(abs(translation / panThreshold))
            if pos < chartImageArray.count {
                print (pos)
                chartView.image = chartImageArray[pos]
            }


        }
```

This does scroll through, but when you release it obviously go back to 0. Is there some better way to achieve this functionality?

I was try to figure out a way to track the transition number and somehow increase or decrease an index number that would correlate to the image `array`.

Thanks
Craig

EDIT: Here is the code I used to get the functionally

```
@objc func panPerformed(_ sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    if sender.state == .began || sender.state == .changed {
        let velocity = sender.velocity(in: self.view).y
        var count = 0
        if velocity > 0 {
            count -= 1
        } else {
            count += 1
        }
        movePictures(count)

    } else if sender.state == .ended { //release swipe

    }
}

func movePictures(_ ind:Int) {
    // print (index)
    if index >= 0 {
        index = index + ind
    } else {
        index = arrayCount * panThreshold
    }
    if index <= arrayCount * panThreshold {
        index = index + ind
    } else {
        index = 0
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have to use a pan recognizer? If not, creating a collectionView of all your images will be a lot easier

Comment: What you are describing is so exactly a UIPageController, so why not use it and solve the problem effortlessly?

Comment: So the images are of musical instrument fingerings... I want the user to be able to quickly get to the note they are looking forward without having to constantly swipe over and over.